# Query to get convex hull

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

Is the below query correct to get a convex hull shape:

DATA "the_geom from (select ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) As the_geom FROM xyz) as foo using unique id using SRID=XXXX"

Comment: Apologies, I have just realized this was about mapserver. Mapserver needs a gid, so I think you will need to use st_dump on the results of convex hull, to get the underlying geometries and an id. I will write up a better answer later.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on realizing this is a MapServer question. I don't have MapServer to test, but I am sure about the convex hull subquery, and read the docs on Mapserver to see how to create a DATA element. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Update, having belatedly realized this is a Map Server question.

In general, to get the convex hull, you will want to group by id/gid, as producing the hull(s) is an aggregate operation. So, without the Mapserver part, the query would look like:

```
SELECT id, ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) as the_geom from xyz group by id;
```

Now, to get MapServer to understand this in a DATA definition, you would do:

```
DATA "the_geom FROM (
   SELECT id as oid, 
   ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) as the_geom 
   FROM xyz group by id
) as some_table USING UNIQUE oid USING SRID=4326"
```

where I have assumed your SRID is 4326.

Original, incorrect answer:

<s>You don't need the SRID at all, unless you wish to transform from one coordinate system to another, or you only want to select geometries with a certain srid in the query -- but it would be a bit unusual to have mixed srid geometries in the same column. There is no need for a sub-query, you can just write,</s>

```
SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom)) as the_hull 
FROM xyz WHERE id=someid;
```

where I have changed the output to `the_hull` to differentiate from the input `the_geom`.
If you really mean to only include geometries with a certain srid, add 
    and st_srid(the_geom)=some_srid`
at the end of the where clause.